# ～たくない vs ～ことが欲しくない

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the nuance between saying

「話したくない」

vs

「話すことが欲しくない」?

Comment: Have you ever seen the second sentence? I don't think a native would say that at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ほしい～ when used to modify an action (verb) indicates that that action is done by parties other than the speaker. For example, 「話してほしい」means [I] want [you] to talk [to me about x]. Used in this sense, ほしい cannot be used to modify actions done by the speaker himself. You cannot say 「話すことがほしくない」if you mean to say "I don't want to talk" because you are the person doing the talking.

Note that this use of ほしい only applies when it is used to modify actions. You can say 「りんごがほしい」"I want an apple" and it would make perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

話すことが欲しくない is simply ungrammatical. It makes no sense. In English, you use the same verb, *want*, to say both "I want [something]" and "I want to [do some action]". In Japanese, you have to use completely different constructions for these meanings, simply because they are different in meaning. You have to say ～が欲しい for "I want [something]", and ～(し)たい for "I want to [do something]".